# Getting Forms Authentication from an ASP.NET logon page used by Silverlight 4 application

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, formsauthentication

This is supposed to just work. I've read all the articles I could find via google on the topic, tried to copy as much as I could from other articles on both StackOverflow and CodeProject and others, but regardless of what I try - it doesn't work.

I have a silverlight application that runs fine using Windows Authentication.

To get it running under Forms Authentication I've:

Edited the web.config file to enable Forms Authentication (and delete the Windows Authentication configuration):

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="logon.aspx" defaultUrl="index.aspx"      protection="All" path="/" timeout="30" />
    </authentication>
```

Created a standard logon.aspx and logon.aspx.cs code behind page to take a user input name and password, and create a authentication cookie when the logon was successful, and then redirected the user to the root page of the web site, which is a silverlight application:

```
    private void cmdLogin_ServerClick( object sender, System.EventArgs e )
    {
        if ( ValidateUser( txtUserName.Value, txtUserPass.Value ) )
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtUserName.Value, true);
            var cookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(txtUserName.Value, true);
            cookie.Domain = "mymachine.mydomain.com";
            this.Response.AppendCookie(cookie);

            string strRedirect;
            strRedirect = Request["ReturnUrl"];
            if ( strRedirect == null )
                strRedirect = "index.aspx";
            Response.Redirect( strRedirect, true );
        }
    }
```

So the redirect after successfully logging in launches my silverlight application.

However the user is not authenticated when executing the Silverlight startup code:

```
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var webContext = new WebContext();
        webContext.Authentication = new FormsAuthentication();
        ApplicationLifetimeObjects.Add( webContext );
    }

    private void ApplicationStartup( object sender, StartupEventArgs e )
    {
        Resources.Add( "WebContext", WebContext.Current );

        // This will automatically authenticate a user when using windows authentication
        // or when the user chose "Keep me signed in" on a previous login attempt
        WebContext.Current.Authentication.LoadUser(ApplicationUserLoaded, null);

        // Show some UI to the user while LoadUser is in progress
        InitializeRootVisual();
    }
```

The error occurs in the ApplicationUserLoaded method, which always has its HasError property set to true on entry to the method.

```
    private void ApplicationUserLoaded( LoadUserOperation operation )
    {
        if((operation != null) && operation.HasError)
        {
            operation.MarkErrorAsHandled();
            HandlerShowWebServiceCallBackError(operation.Error, "Error loading user context.");
            return;
        }
        ...
    }
```

The error reported is as follows - from what it appears to me is that the user isn't considered authenticated on entry to the silverlight app, so it is directing the code to try to return the logon page, which is returning data unexpected by the silverlight app:

```
An exception occurred while attempting to contact the web service.
Please try again, and if the error persists, contact your administrator.

Error details:
Error loading user context.

Exception details:
Load operation failed for query 'GetUser'. The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
```

Any ideas?

Based on everything I read, this is supposed to be pretty simple and just work - so I'm obviously making a very basic error.

I'm wondering if after I authenticate the user on my logon.aspx web page, I need to somehow pass an authenticated WebContext instance over from the logon page to my silverlight application instead of creating a new instance in the silverlight app startup code - but have no idea how to do that.

Appreciate any or all suggestions.

Comment: So iirc by default Silverlight projects are set up as Forms Authentication. Have you tried creating a default project and compare settings?

Comment: I have a strong doubt that it is going to work if you're just going to create a new instance of `FormsAuthentication`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not very experienced at writing Silverlight apps from scratch, but have had a fair bit of experience in modifying existing ones. I just created a default Silverlight Hello World type application but didn't get any obvious clues by comparing the settings :-(

Comment: Kassem - I agree that this is most likely the cause of my problem. There has to be a way of using the forms authentication credentials generated via my logon.aspx page in my silverlight application - but none of the articles I've seen have provided me enough details about how to get it to work. They seem to indicate that the generated cookie should have been used by the silverlight app to obtain and use the user's form authenticated credentials. They are a host of articles saying that this is possible - I'm hoping someone knows what the trick is that I'm missing.

Comment: Actually I've never used FormsAuthentication with Silverlight. I've been writing Silverlight apps for the past 6 months. I usually create a login page INSIDE Silverlight which calls a WCF service to check the credentials against a data store and returns back the result to the client (Silverlight). At work, we also have a framework which integrates Silverlight with WIF to use Claims based authentication and the save the authenticated identity into the application's main thread.

Comment: Can you comment the line where you create a new instance of FormsAuthentication class? I also read that Silverlight should use the cookie after the user has been authenticated. So I'm guessing you do not need that line of code... I donno, give it a try and let's see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the `Response.Redirect("...", true);`

[According to this article you should pass false to keep the session](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2004/08/03/207486.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Elmo - you're right. However unfortunately it didn't fix my problem - results were the same.

Comment: When you add a LoginView control to the aspx page that contains the SL App, does it indicate an authenticated user?

Comment: Yes. The aspx page indicates an authenticated user. On entry to the SL App, there is no sign of the authenticated user.